# ios 7 orientation issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, orientation

In my App (deployment target iOS 7) for showing Pictures using **Navigation Controller with root view controller (support portrait only)**

[ pushes —> ]

**Image view controller (support portrait & landscape)**
In this image are shown using **page View Controller**

[ then presents —> ]

**MPMovieplayer(support portrait & landscape)**

on dismiss from movie player and popping to portrait only root view controller it turned to landscape.

I have given these in root view controller

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

I need this controller not going to landscape at any scenarios..
i have handled the orientation in Image View controller using the delegates

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

}


- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {

}
```

In Image view controller like this

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: implement a subset of the `UINavigationController` and present the orientation support from the actually visible view controller only. originally the `UINavigationController` does not really care of its individual view controllers orientation wish – therefore you need to override the related methods in your subset.

Comment: I made a navigation controller classa and put 
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
this did't worked 
is this you have mention...?

Comment: it does not do the job for you, because this is not what I mentioned. :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got this fixed on using this checking in **Appdelegate**

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
    // Get topmost/visible view controller
    UIViewController *currentViewController = [self.navigationController topViewController];

    // Unlock landscape view orientations for this view controller
    if([navigationController.topViewController isKindOfClass:[ImsgeViewController class]])
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    }
    else if([navigationController.topViewController isKindOfClass:[PageContentViewController class]])
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    }
    // Only allow portrait (standard behaviour)
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```